# I've been trying to build a dc.js datatable with pagination.How to fix 'Pagination for dc.table'?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to add pagination to dc.datatable .

The pagination is not working and not displaying pages.

With this code the whole data table is showing up,and just the 'next' and 'prev' button at the end of the table but the buttons are not functioning.

How to fix pagination which shows 20 rows at one page?

My Code

```
 <div class="chart col-sm-12" id="all-characters-div">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <h2>Comic Characters</h2>
                <table id="all-characters"> </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pagination">
            <span id="start"></span>-<span id="end"></span> of <span id="totalSize"></span>
            <button id="prev" class="btn" onclick="prev()">Prev</button>
            <button id="next" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next</button>
        </div>

function makeGraphs(error, charactersData) {
    var ndx = crossfilter(charactersData);

show_listCharacters(ndx);
       updateResult();
         dc.renderAll();

 function show_listCharacters(ndx) {  
   var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#all-characters");

   var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("name"));
 // console.log(dim.top(Infinity));
       dataTable
      .dimension(dim)
      .group(function(d) {
        return "";
      })
      .columns(["name", "urlslug", "first appearance"])
      .size(Infinity)
      .sortBy(dc.pluck("name")) 
      .order(d3.ascending)
      .transitionDuration(1000);
       }
  /*-----------------Table Pagination-----------*/
          var resultStart = 0; var resultEnd =21;
          var ndx;
          var dataTable = dc.dataTable;

          function displayResult() {

            document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = resultStart;
            document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = resultStart + resultEnd-1;

            document.getElementById("totalSize").innerHTML = ndx.size();


            d3.select('#prev').attr('disabled', resultStart-resultEnd < 0 ? 'true' : null);
            d3.select('#next').attr('disabled', resultStart+resultEnd >= ndx.size() ? 'true' : null);
        }
          function updateResult() {

            dataTable.beginSlice(resultStart);
            dataTable.endSlice(resultStart + resultEnd);
            displayResult();

        }
        function prev() {
          resultStart -= resultEnd;
          updateResult();
          dataTable.redraw();
        }
          function next() {
            resultStart += resultEnd;
            updateResult();
            dataTable.redraw();
        }
```

Comment: you should include your html

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions regarding the charting library. [dc] is a classic unix calculator utility.

Comment: I haven't tested your code - hope to take a look in the next day or two. But have you looked at [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/table-pagination.html)? It's fairly robust. I am sure that @Xavier's is too.

Answer (score 1):

look at the code in this project: https://tttp.eu I have pagination and sortable columns

the relevant part

```
 function drawPagination(){

  var ofs = 0, pag = 10;
  chart.on('preRedraw.pagination', display);

  function display() {
      d3.select('#begin')
          .text(1+ofs);
      d3.select('#end')
          .text(ofs+pag);
      d3.selectAll('#next,#last')
          .attr('disabled', ofs+pag>=graphs.total.data() ? 'true' : null);
      d3.selectAll('#first,#prev')
          .attr('disabled', ofs<=0 ? 'true' : null);
      d3.select('#size').text(graphs.total.data());
  }

  function update() {
      chart.beginSlice(ofs);
      chart.endSlice(ofs+pag);
      chart.redraw();
  }

  function next() {
      ofs += pag;update();
  }
  function prev() {
      ofs -= pag;
      if (ofs <=0) {
        d3.selectAll("#prev,#first").attr("disabled",true);
        ofs=0;
      }
      update();
  }

  d3.selectAll("#pagination")
    .html (`
        Showing <span id="begin"></span>-<span id="end"></span> of <span id="size"></span><span class="btn-group">
        <button id="first" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></i>First</button>
        <button id="prev" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i>Prev</button>
        <button id="next" class="btn btn-primary">Next<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></i></button>
        <button id="last" class="btn btn-primary">Last<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></i></button>
        </span>
    `);
  d3.select("#first").on("click",function(){ofs=0;update()});
  d3.select("#last").on("click",function(){ofs=graphs.total.data()-pag;update()});
  d3.select("#prev").on("click",prev);
  d3.select("#next").on("click",function(){ofs +=pag;update()});

  update();
}
```